# Cannot call class as a function

Tags: javascript, ember.js, frontend

I am currently facing an issue with computed properties, I have a model named crossconnection containing some computed properties like :

```
relevantPoints: computed(function () {

    if (this.get('IsCA') === true && this.get('IsCM') === true) {
        return "/assets/images/big/ca-cm.png";
    }
    else if (this.get('IsCA') === true && this.get('IsCM') === false) {
        return "/assets/images/big/ca.png";
    }
    else if (this.get('IsCA') === false && this.get('IsCM') === true) {
        return "/assets/images/big/cm.png";
    }
    else if (this.get('IsCA') === false && this.get('IsCM') === false) {
        return "/assets/images/big/nca-ncm.png";
    }

}),
```

when running the project I keep getting the following error :

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function**

Can somebody please clarify ?

---

PS : 
I am using,

- Ember           : 3.0.0
- Ember Data      : 3.0.2
- jQuery          : 3.3.1

---

***Update :***

Clarifications : I have a model 'crossconnection ' that contains some computed properties, my model is called from the controller via a simple

```
from = this.store.query('crossconnection ', {
            fromOpKey: this.get('opSelected').get('opKey'),
            limit: -1
        });
```

Which then causes the following error (full stack trace attached)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
    at classCallCheck (ember-babel.js:11)
    at Object.Class [as Object] (core_object.js:25)
    at Module.callback (crossconnection.js:65)
    at Module.exports (loader.js:106)
    at requireModule (loader.js:27)
    at Class._extractDefaultExport (index.js:410)
    at Class.resolveOther (index.js:110)
    at Class.superWrapper [as resolveOther] (ember-utils.js:420)
    at Class.resolve (resolver.js:133)
    at _resolve (container.js:871)
classCallCheck  @   ember-babel.js:11
Class   @   core_object.js:25
(anonymous) @   crossconnection.js:65
Module.exports  @   loader.js:106
requireModule   @   loader.js:27
_extractDefaultExport   @   index.js:410
resolveOther    @   index.js:110
superWrapper    @   ember-utils.js:420
resolve @   resolver.js:133
_resolve    @   container.js:871
resolve @   container.js:574
resolve @   container.js:578
factoryFor  @   container.js:136
factoryFor  @   container_proxy.js:40
modelFactoryFor @   -private.js:11593
_modelFactoryFor    @   -private.js:11556
_modelFor   @   -private.js:11547
modelFor    @   -private.js:11540
_query  @   -private.js:8666
_query  @   -private.js:10819
query   @   -private.js:10806
(anonymous) @   ops.js:55
applyStr    @   ember-utils.js:524
sendEvent   @   ember-metal.js:257
notifyObservers @   ember-metal.js:1103
propertyDidChange   @   ember-metal.js:886
set @   ember-metal.js:2893
set @   observable.js:104
openOpPopupWithKey  @   ops.js:143
send    @   action_handler.js:28
(anonymous) @   action.js:124
exports.flaggedInstrument   @   ember-metal.js:3920
(anonymous) @   action.js:123
_run    @   backburner.js:758
_join   @   backburner.js:736
join    @   backburner.js:477
run.join    @   ember-metal.js:4366
handler @   action.js:102
(anonymous) @   event_dispatcher.js:234
dispatch    @   jquery.js:5183
elemData.handle @   jquery.js:4991
```

Comment: How do you `call` the `function`?

Comment: The relevant code isn't here. You'll need to write a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get an answer.

Comment: I am not, this is just at model stage, still haven't begun writing a controller for it, when trying to run the project, it fails stating the error mentioned above

Comment: Instead of just prodiving the computed property provide the entire file.

Comment: There’s a syntax error in the computed property. Computed is part of Ember API and requires multiple arguments.

Comment: how do you access this computed property?

Comment: And could you attach a stack trace?

Comment: @runspired I access it by simply querying the store via controller

Comment: Could it be the import syntax of computed?  Can you share that?

Answer (score 6):

Please make sure you import `computed` correctly:

`import { computed } from '@ember/object';`

Answer (score 1):

Edit - this doesn’t seem to be the cause of the error, but I’ll leave it here for now

You are missing an argument in your computed. Computed takes first the attributes to watch as strings, and then the callback function:

```
relevantPoints: computed(‘isCA’, ‘isCM’, function () {

    if (this.get('IsCA') === true && this.get('IsCM') === true) {
        return "/assets/images/big/ca-cm.png";
    }
 ...,
}),
```

*This answer applies to 1.13 through 3.x, with one small modification to the code snippets for < 3.0. App versions less than 3.0 should do Ember.computed instead of computed.*

Comment: Dependent keys are only necessary when you need to specify when invalidation of the computed should occur, but they aren't mandatory.